# BreezeSharp - Is there any equivalent of AsNoTracking

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

I'm caching some objects on the client side local cache in a WPF app. I'd like to fetch the data from server when the app starts and then disconnect the EntityManager so that it doesn't maintain another copy of the objects.

Is there any overload of ExecuteQuery that doesn't cache the object in EntityManager? or should I be using a different way of achieving this?

Comment: Looks like this tag is dead... I see that even the creators of breeze haven't answered anything here for months..

Comment: Is BreezeSharp not a supported product?